# Git Rebase but replacing instead of patching file?

Tags: git

I want the perform a manipulation similar to rebase except that when applying revision X to revision Y, it applies all files changed during (X^..X) with the exact state of revision X instead of applying the patch of diff (X^..X) to Y. 
And, of course, the commit date, message, author name, and author email etc are as same as revision X.

For example, I have a git repo structure as following:

```
A-B-C-D-E
```

And I "rebase" it to this:

```
A-B-E'-D'-C'
```

If B has file a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, and E modifies file, we get file a.txt as same as E and b.txt and c.txt as same as B in the revision E'. (While in normal rebase, we get a.txt in a state of B+(D..E) in E')

Any illustration for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `git cherry-pick <commit>`
[Man Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html)

cherry-pick attempts to apply the changes of a single commit to the current revision.

You would want to check out `B`, then cherry pick `E`, and that would probably give you `E'`. You can then continue to cherry pick `D` and `C`, or do a full rebase onto `E'` if that makes more sense.

Since this command only applies the changes of `E`, you're skipping any changes that might be in `D` or `C`. If you want `E'` to contain the same revision of a file that's in `E`, your only option might be to copy that file, check out `B`, and make a new commit.